# Fixed element alignment to always stick to the bottom of the screen

Tags: css, css-float

I have a fixed element that is a small menu with a few links that will follow you on the page.

I am using Squarespace and make a new widget with the links. In the CSS I put this code:

```
#moduleContent18520661 { 
    position:fixed  !important;
    margin: auto;
    top:700px;
    left:400px;
    cursor:hand;
    background:#efefef;
    border:1px solid #ffcc00;
    width:480px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

It works perfect only when I align it on my computer. When I look on my laptop it's too far down.

How can I pin the element to always be on the bottom of the screen no matter what size the screen is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `position: fixed` you can explicitly position to the bottom, or any other side, of the screen:

```
#moduleContent18520661 {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; /* the bottom edge of the element will
                  sit against the bottom edge of the window */
    /* other stuff */
}
```

Just remove the `top` declaration and replace with the distance you want the bottom edge of the element to to maintain from the bottom edge of the window.

Also, `cursor` should either be `cursor: pointer;` *or* should have `cursor: pointer;` follow the `cursor: hand;`, as that's a purely IE 6 (if I remember correctly) proprietary CSS property value.

Comment: Thank you so much this is the code I put in.

#moduleContent18520661 { 
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto; 
  left:400px; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  cursor:hand ;
  background:#efefef;
  border:1px solid ;#ffcc00;
  width:480px;
  z-index:100;/*}

It work perfect.